# python ftp files thread or multiprocess

Tags: python

We continously generate data files from our database which are then FTP'D to different locations. We have a poler that continously monitors this folder and as soon as it sees files it FTP's them

currently this process is sequential and when the files get large there is a backup which causes significant delay. I would like to process things in parallel i.e FTP multiple files at one times. I am not sure about threading/ multiprocessing and how this would work for me.

here is my code

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP('domainname.com')
ftp.login("username","password")
infiles = [file1,file2,file3.....filen]
for x in infiles:
    f = open(x,'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' %x, f)
    f.close()
ftp.quit()
```

I am thinking since this is I/O intensive Multiprocessing is the way to go, any ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) useful as a higher level interface.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def upload(file): 
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('domainname.com')
    ftp.login("username","password")
    f = open(file,'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' %x, f)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit()


infiles = [file1,file2,file3.....filen]

pool = Pool(10) # submit 10 at once
pool.map(upload,infiles)
```

It's nice because `map` behaves like the builtin function. For debugging just replace the `pool.map` --> `map`.

Comment: If it is I/O bound then you could use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead (the interface is identical, the only change is the import).

Comment: @Contestosis, yes. Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a code snippet at hand, but for a production environment I would definitivly look at [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Twisted is not the easiest tool to get started with, but it brings a lot of stuff you will implement later on your own. So I would recommend to spend at least a few hours checking it out.

Answer (score -1):

put the time consuming task into a function

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def upload_file(filename):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('domainname.com')
    ftp.login("username","password")
    f = open(x,'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' %x, f)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit() 

def multi_ftp():
    files = [file1, file2, ...]
    processes = []
    for filename in files:
        p = Process(target=filename, args=(filename,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```